# Blogger widget HTML type not showing content

Tags: html, templates, blogs, blogger

I am trying to create a custom blogger template and I would like to add a featured posts section, but my content is not showing in my blog.

This is my code:

```
<b:section id='featured-slider' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='yes'>
  <b:widget id='HTML5' locked='true' title='Featured' type='HTML'>
    <b:includable id='main'>

<!-- posts -->
<div class='featured-container'>

<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
<b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;featured&quot;'>

<div class='featured-post'>
<img class='featured-post-img' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:src='data:post.firstImageUrl'/>
<h2 class='featured-post-title'><data:post.title/></h2>
</div>
</b:if>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
  </b:if>
</b:loop>

</div>

</b:includable>

  </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

However, if I change widget type to "Blog", the content shows:

```
<b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Featured' type='Blog'>
```

Why with a "HTML" type is not working? Do you know any other alternative way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I achive to show my featured posts using JSON, here is an example: [Thumbnails From External Sources Are Not Appearing In Random Posts Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585558/thumbnails-from-external-sources-are-not-appearing-in-random-posts-widget)

Answer (score 0):

In blogger template each widget type uses different data as mentioned in the [Layouts Data Tags](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270) and you can only use one featured post widget in your template.

Comment: I only use a featured post widget (the code I pasted).However content is not showing if the type is "HTML", and I don't understand why.

Comment: Try to change the type to type='FeaturedPost'

Comment: It doesn´t work either. Just with "Blog" type, but only want a Blog type widget (main widget). Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Please read  [Layouts Data Tags](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270) carefully to understand how it works.